# Sending Selected Field Data using PHP and API's

Tags: php, forms, api, html-select

I am using an API to submit form data to a third party CRM database.

Here is the html of the form...

```
        <div class="column last">
          <label for="role">What is your role?</label>
          <select name="role" id="role">
            <option value="noresponse">Please select one</option>
            <option value="reseller">Reseller</option>
            <option value="researcher">Researcher</option>
            <option value="end-user">End-user</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
          </select>
        </div>
```

And here is the php that sends the selected field data using an API.

```
<?php
    //Process a new form submission in HubSpot in order to create a new Contact.
    $hubspotutk = $_COOKIE['hubspotutk'];  //grab the cookie from the visitors browser.
    $ip_addr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  //IP address too.
    $hs_context = array(
            'hutk' => $hubspotutk,
            'ipAddress' => $ip_addr,
            'pageUrl' => 'http://www.suntechmed.com/index.php?option=com_chronoforms&chronoform=test_form',
            'pageName' => 'Test Form'
        );

    $hs_context_json = json_encode($hs_context);
    //Need to populate these varilables with values from the form.
    $str_post = "firstname=" . urlencode($_POST["firstname"])
                        . "&lastname=" . urlencode($_POST["lastname"])
                        . "&company=" . urlencode($_POST["company"])
            . "&role=" . urlencode($POST["role"])            
            . "&address=" . urlencode($_POST["address"])
            . "&city=" . urlencode($_POST["city"])
            . "&state=" . urlencode($_POST["state"])
            . "&zip=" . urlencode($_POST["zip"])
            . "&email=" . urlencode($_POST["email"])
                        . "&hs_context=" . urlencode($hs_context_json);  //Leave this one be :)'

     //replace the values in this URL with your portal ID and your form GUID
    $endpoint = 'https://forms.hubspot.com/uploads/form/v2/myHubspotID/b9752739-c9a3-4dc3-bf34-cb23679a41d4';
    $ch = @curl_init();
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $str_post);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = @curl_exec($ch);  //Log the response from HubSpot as needed.
    @curl_close($ch);
    echo $response;
    ?>
```

The fields that are simple text fields make the transition just fine.

The problem I am having is that the fields that have select options (like "role") are not making it to the database.

In fact, it doesn't even show role as an empty field.

If anybody has any suggestions, that would be grand!

Comment: You left out the `_` in `$_POST['role']`.

Answer (score 1):

Create an send has their own API writen on php you can add users by doing something like this:

($donation->subscribe_to_newsletter === true) {
        require_once('system/cm/csrest_subscribers.php');

```
    $wrap = new CS_REST_Subscribers(CS_REST_DONATE_LIST_ID, CS_REST_DONATE_API_KEY);
    $result = $wrap->add(array(
        'EmailAddress' => $donation->email,
        'Name' => sprintf('%s %s', $donation->first_name, $donation->last_name),
        'CustomFields' => array(),
        'Resubscribe' => true
    ));
```

You can find all the php files and even some examples on their [github](https://github.com/campaignmonitor/createsend-php)

Comment: This answer is irrelevant. The question doesn't mention anything about the CreateSend/CampaignMonitor API.

Comment: I would say affirming the "answer is irrelevant" is short minded, the user is clearly using create and send api and the first thing the answer states is that is reference to the Create and send API so is not misleading to users having trouble reading

Comment: The user is using the HubSpot API. Where do you see CreateSend mentioned?